# Как можно инициализировать безразмерный массив в .c файле

Tags: c

Создал в .h файле массив вида:

```
typedef void (*func)(void);
func fn[];
```

Как можно в .c файле инициализировать массив 'fn[]' ?

Comment: Это не безразмерный массив, это массив фиксированного размера, причем размер определяется из инициализатора. А инициализация ничем не отличается от инициализации массива с предварительным указанием размера.

Answer (score 3):

Массивы всегда имеют фиксированный размер, заданный во время компиляции. Они задаются числом или списком данных. В `.h` файле не желательно объявлять переменную, будет ошибка двойного определения. Только в `.c` фале нужно.

.h :

```
typedef void (*func)(void);
extern func fn[];
extern func fm[];
extern func fn1[];
extern func fn2[];
```

.c :

```
// массив размера одного элемента (1)
func fn1[];
// массив с чётким размером (2)
func fn2[2];
// массив с размерностью, заданной данными (3)
func fn[]={NULL,NULL,NULL};
// массив с размерностью, заданной данными и индексами (101)
func fm[]={[0] = NULL,[10] = NULL,[100] = NULL};
```

Если вы хотели массив с плавающим размером, то можно просто выделить для него память.

.h :

```
extern func * fn ;
```

.c :

```
void fun(void) {
  .. выделение памяти нужного размера
  fn = (func *)malloc(sizeof(func) * 2);
  // назначение указателя
  fn[1] = fun ;
  // вызов
  fn[1]();
  // освобождение памяти
  free(fn); }
```